# How to perform testing on a legacy system tightly coupled with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jpa, testing

I am working with a legacy codebase using Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.1.4. By legacy I mean that there are no tests written whatsoever.
The problem I stumbled on is the choice between writing pure unit tests, or a smaller version of integration test.

Here is my unit test in JUnit:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(TestConfiguration.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestService1.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.properties")
public class SomeTest {
    protected BusinessObject businessObject;
    @MockBean
    private UnimportantService someService;
    @MockBean
    private UnimportantRepo someRepo;
    // and a lot of MockBeans like that to inject into our TestService1

    @Autowired
    private TestService1 serviceInTest;
    @Before
    public void initResource() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        // init business object
        businessObject = new BusinessObject();
        businessObject.setAddressLine1("sth");
        // .......

        Stuff stuff = new Stuff(code);
        stuff.setName("some thing");
        // ...

        // Mocking part
        when(someService.getStuff(code)).thenReturn(stuff);
        when(someRepo.save(any(BusinessObject.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<BusinessObject>() {
            @Override
            public BusinessObject answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                BusinessObject acc =  (BusinessObject) args[0];
                return acc;
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        BusinessObject obj = this.serviceInTest.create(businessObject);
        assertEquals(obj.getStatus(), SUCCESSFUL);
    }
}
```

The problem is with the code for `TestService1` and the `BusinessObject` entity are pretty coupled to Spring and JPA.

```java
@Service("testService")
public class TestService1 {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;

    @Autowired
    private UnimportantService someService;
    @Autowired
    private UnimportantRepo someRepo;
    // and a lot of autowired component, but i will skip it

    @PostConstruct
    protected void onPostConstruct() {
        // initialize something
    }
}

@Entity
@Table
public class BusinessObject extends AbstractUpdatableUuidEntity {

    @Column(name = "someAttribute", columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String someAttribute;
    // and some more attributes , but those are not important


    @PrePersist
    @Override
    protected void onPrePersist() {
        super.onPrePersist();
        // init some field in the AbstractUpdatableUuidEntity...
    }
    public enum Status {
        FAILED,
        IN_PROGRESS,
        OPENED,
        SUCCESSFUL,
    }
}
```

If I run plainly without Spring then the `onPostConstruct` wouldn't run and the `activeProfile` would not be set, so I made a compromise (still acceptable) and added a little Spring in my unit test.

But then for the `BusinessObject` Entity, I have already mocked a repo call, but if I do this way without JPA, the `onPrePersist` wouldn't run, which will fail the test. But if I added JPA and dont mock the repository, the load time increased to 9s, which might as well has already become an integration test. Even worse, this `SomeTest` context will not be cached to another test, because it is too fine-grained for testing that service only.

```java
when(someRepo.save(any(BusinessObject.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<BusinessObject>() {
            @Override
            public BusinessObject answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                BusinessObject acc =  (BusinessObject) args[0];
                return acc;
            }
        });
```

Any advice on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, it seems like the test is slowly turning into an integration test more than unit test. If the main problem it's the onPostConstruct method you can just:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws NoSuchMethodException,  InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException
    Method postConstruct =  MyService.class.getDeclaredMethod("onPostConstruct",null); 
    postConstruct.setAccessible(true);
    postConstruct.invoke(testTarget);
}
```

And in future revisions of the code see if the postconstruct isn't neccesary.

I would also rather suggest to change your injection method from field injection to constructor injection. It makes a lot easier to unit test your code, for example if in the @PostConstruct you are just operating with @Value you can do it in the constructor itself, and get rid of it.

Comment: I am not quite sure about that.
The postconstruct hack does the work, but it seems very makeshift. And the code in onPostConstruct and onPrePersist,  is quite necessary.

The constructor injection i must agree.

Thanks for your help. Like, a lot. But there is still some choke point here.